# trying to prevent the cursor from jumping to a different inputfield

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using the submit type because i want the ability to hit enter instead of manually clicking on the button. i know how to prevent it, but not how to keep it the cursor in the same inputfield, since the inputfield will create a new div within an inputfield and it automatically jumps to that one.

```
<form @submit.prevent="createNewList">
    <input
        type="text"
        class="form fs-4 me-3"
        placeholder="input something here..."
        v-model="listName"
        :maxlength="20"
    />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success bi-clipboard-plus"></button>
</form>
```

this is what i have so far. i tried putting "@keydown.enter.prevent" within the input-tag but it caused the enter to not work.
what else could i try

Comment: "_since the inputfield will create a new div within an inputfield_".  How?  Your code implies no such thing.  As it is now, hitting the enter key with the cursor inside the only input will cause the `createNewList` function to run, and the cursor remains inside the input.  Is that not what you're experiencing?

Comment: Please review [How to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `submit` you can also use `keypress.enter` and then your cursor should remain in the input field.

```
<input
  type="text"
  class="form fs-4 me-3"
  placeholder="input something here..."
  v-model="listName"
  :maxlength="20"
  @keypress.enter="callYourFunction()"
 />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success bi-clipboard-plus" @click="callYourFunction()"></button>
```